# Anti-italic in an Italic Environment

Tags: bold, amsthm, italic

I am using a `theorem` environment with style `plain`. So far, everything looks great, except that the item indices are italic. The example code is

```
\begin{proposition}
    Some properties of the cdf $F$ are:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[\textbf{(i)}] $F(b)$ is a nondecreasing function of $b$, 
        \item[\textbf{(ii)}] $\lim_{b \to \infty} F(b) = F(\infty) = 1$,
        \item[\textbf{(iii)}] $\lim_{b \to \infty} F(b) = F(-\infty) = 0$. 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{proposition}
```

in which the `proposition` is given by

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
```

And the output is

[image]

**Is there any way to make the indices `(i)` `(ii)` and `(iii)` bold but not italic?** I have tried to put `\textbf{i}` in a `\text{}`, but it's not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A good idea would be to use `enumitem` and to define a special environment for “theorem enumerations”, so as to ensure consistency across the document.

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{thmenum}
 {\begin{enumerate}[label=\upshape\bfseries(\roman*)]}
 {\end{enumerate}}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}
Some properties of the cdf $F$ are:
\begin{thmenum}
  \item $F(b)$ is a nondecreasing function of $b$,
  \item $\lim_{b \to \infty} F(b) = F(\infty) = 1$,
  \item $\lim_{b \to \infty} F(b) = F(-\infty) = 0$.
\end{thmenum}
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Doing this way allows to avoid explicit font specifications in the enumerations inside theorem statements and you can change the formatting by just acting on the definition of `thmenum`. I'd recommend removing `\bfseries`, for instance, but you can try both ways and then decide.

Comment: Looks like we posted the same solution at the same time. You were a few seconds ahead, so I’ll delete mine.